# joining two mysql tables without unique common field

Tags: php, mysql, join

I made a big mistake in inserting data from my survey application and now I really stuck! I have list of movies in my table **"featuredfilms_EN"** with these fields: **movieName, ImdbId(unique Id of movies), year.** In my survey app, I asked users about their favorite movies and I stored their answers in the **"Answer_CROWD"** table which has these fields: **qId, answer.** 
Now I faced a big problem that is: I need to join these two tables, but since I forgot to store the unique_Id(ImdbId) in "Answer_CROWD" table, I cannot!:(

I appreciate if someone can help me if there is a way that I can join these two tables? I am really stuck... I have a deadline tomorrow and I just found this big issue now.

Comment: question number in the survey.., for example question 1-> q1

Comment: What does `answer` contain? Movie name?

Comment: @ReneKorss: yes, it has movieName_year, for example: Titanic_1997

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: yes, sure, Ill update my question in 2 min

Comment: Probably if i understand you don't use join because there aren't two bounded fields to join. But in answer field of table answer_crowd do you save also films informations like titles?

Comment: @LucaOlivieri: yes, in `answer` column, I stored movieName_year, for instance `Titanic_1997`

Comment: Please. No pictures. Just proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle)

Comment: @Strawberry: sorry, ok, should I remove images now?

Comment: i suggest to create an other field in answer_crowd with id of featured_films. Update it getting all  concat(trim(movieName), '_', year)and id from Featuredfilms_EN .Then in a update query for Answer_CROWD answer=concat(trim(movieName), '_', year)you can set in an other field that you can add, Film_id the id. In this way you can restore informations and then do join with two numeric fields, in a better way.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1538/1 is the SQL-Fiddle I made based on the pictures

Comment: @LucaOlivieri: thanks, this is exactly what I needed! but I'm just a bit confused about how to write the Update query, I am worried to just make more problems in my DB..could I kindly ask you about the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you could concat the movieName & year & match on that

```
SELECT * FROM featuredfilms_EN 
JOIN Answer_CROWD ON lower(answer)=lower(concat(trim(movieName), '_', year))
```

Comment: thanks for help, what if there are two movies with the same title in the same year?

Comment: I hope the names match - just went to refer back to your pictures & they are gone :-(

Comment: Unfortunately no easy way around that one as your answer will have the same data in it - there would be no easy way around selecting those - you would need to manually sort those as there appears to be insufficient information to do it automatically (Do you know what the result should be ??)

Comment: You are right. My professor asked me to use string match, but I don't know how to do that.. what is your idea?

Comment: Isn't that what my answer does - matches the answer to the string made up by the concat of the film title & year)

Comment: because I get `count(*)` from "Answer_CROWD" and it was 1253 rows, while when I get `count(distinct answer)`, it shows 1082 rows..

Comment: Spelling mistakes in the answer ?? I've just edited the answer to trim trailing spaces on the movie name - does that help. If you have the same movie title/year you would get more results.

Comment: I ran both of your query, they both returned me 1243 rows.. so since "Answer_CROWD" contained 1253 rows, how could I find the missing 10 rows? Isn't there any problem if I just skip them?

Comment: I've also modified to query to make it case-insensitive if you table has a binary collation. I will look at a query to select missing answers

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, all 3 queries that you wrote returned me "1243" rows (missing 10 rows, I fund that 5 of these rows is because user inserted nothing in the answer field so it was '')

Comment: This should select all answers with no matching films : "SELECT * FROM Answer_CROWD 
WHERE 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM featuredfilms_EN WHERE lower(answer)=lower(concat(trim(movieName), '_', year)))=0"

Answer (score 1):

I write here  because in comment will be confused,
now i can't see fields of tables so i write generic but i'think you understand:

update query:

1 add a field called for example **Film_id** to **Answer_CROWD**

2 select id,concat(trim(movieName), '_', year) as title from Featuredfilms_EN  and put in $rows

3 in a

```
`foreach ($rows as $value ){
$id=$value['id'];
$title=$value['title'];
$sql="UPDATE Answer_CROWD SET Film_id='$id' WHERE  lower(answer)=lower('$title')";

....do query

}`
```

Comment: sorry to disturb you again, just one more question: I have the same problem for castNames, I mean I also forgot to get castId, so in `Answer_CROWD`, I have only `castName` and in table `Cast` I have `castName` and `castID`. So in this case there could be more casts with similar names :((( (for movies, it was less probable because it also checked the movie_year).. do you have any idea for this one too?

Comment: i ' dont't  understand :castName in answer_crowd and castName in cast are the the same? the same format? similar names it's not same!?

Comment: I mean for the movieName, since I could join based on both movieName and the movie_year, the probability that there would be two exactly same movies with the same name in the same year was lower. But for cast there could be many casts with similar names.. how can I join `Answer_CROWD` and `Cast` table? (in Answer_CROWD fields are userId, qId and answer, so the answer to the question of "who are your favorite casts"  will be saved in `answer` field of Answer_CROWD). hope I could be clear.

Comment: `answer` in Answer_CROWD can keep cast names or movie names or director names, depending of what was the question in my survey.

Comment: you can use the same function adding on other field cast_id to table answer_crowd, then update with query matching names.After you will have 2 new fields film_id and cast_id. If answer refers to cast film_id will be 0 and cast_id >0 . And you can join cast_id with the id of the table cast.